# Deixar alguns dados de uma interface java não obrigatorios

Tags: java, interface

Eu utilizo interfaces para fazer o callback no android.

```
public interface CallbackUsuario {
    void resultadoSalvar(boolean b);
    void resultadoTrazer(Usuario u);
    void resultadoListar(List<Usuario> lista);
    void resultadoExcluir(boolean b);
    void falha(String f);
}
```

Só que as vezes alguns métodos que tem la não são necessários. Por exemplo: vamos supor que eu vou salvar um usuário, então não a necessidade de eu ver os resultados de trazer, listar, e excluir.

Tem como deixá-los não obrigatorios, ou seja só importar o que se espera do retorno?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso não é possível em Java, e também não é possível em nenhuma linguagem (exceto as dinâmicas) que eu conheça. Isso é contrário à ideia de interface, pois o conceito de interfaces implica que uma classe que implemente uma interface garanta, como em um contrato, o cumprimento da interface como um todo e não parcialmente. Deixar de implementar parte de uma interface é equivalente a descumprir um contrato! O "chamador" de uma interface não precisa se preocupar se o implementador desta trata somente esse ou aquele método apenas e pode assumir que ele "sabe" tratar toda a interface.

Contudo, como uma classe Java pode implementar múltiplas interfaces, eu segregaria essas interfaces em diferentes interfaces e apenas implementaria as necessárias para cada caso. Isso tem diversas vantagens, pois permite ao código que "chama" o callback inspecionar se a classe passada implementa, ou não uma das interfaces, apenas chamando as implementadas, e evita que você tenha que implementar na sua classe todos os métodos. Faria algo assim:

```
public interface ICallbackSalvamentoUsuario {
    void resultadoSalvar(boolean b);
}
public interface ICallbackResultadoUsuario {
    void resultadoTrazer(Usuario u);
}
public interface ICallbackLeituraUsuario {
    void resultadoListar(List<Usuario> lista);
}
public interface ICallbackResultadoExclusaoUsuario {
    void resultadoExcluir(boolean b);
}
public interface ICallbackFalhaUsuario {
    void falha(String f);
}
```

Assim, uma classe que permita salvar, listar e o resultado de um usuário seria assim:

```
public class MinhaClasseUsuario implements 
    ICallbackSalvamentoUsuario,
    ICallbackResultadoUsuario,
    ICallbackLeituraUsuario  {

    public void resultadoSalvar(boolean b) {
    }
    public void resultadoTrazer(Usuario u) {
    }
    public void resultadoListar(List<Usuario> lista) {
    }
}
```

Já uma atividade android que permita a exclusão de usuários poderia ser implementada assim:

```
public class AtividadeExclusao extends AppCompatActivity 
    implements 
        ICallbackExclusaoUsuario,
        ICallbackLeituraUsuario {

    public void resultadoExcluir(boolean b) {
    }

    public void resultadoListar(List<Usuario> lista) {
    }
}
```

Claro, o nome das interfaces e dos métodos você decide. Como não conheço sua arquitetura, apenas usei nomes de exemplo, o importante é entender o conceito!

E você pode também criar interfaces que estendam mais de uma das interfaces acima, permitindo combinar as interfaces acima em grupos que facilitem na hora de definir as interfaces que uma classe implemente. Sua CallbackUsuario inicial seria assim definida:

```
public interface ICallbackUsuario extends 
    ICallbackSalvamentoUsuario,
    ICallbackResultadoUsuario,
    ICallbackLeituraUsuario,
    ICallbackResultadoExclusaoUsuario,
    ICallbackFalhaUsuario {
}   

public class XYP implements ICallbackUsuario {

    public void resultadoSalvar(boolean b) {
    }
    public void resultadoTrazer(Usuario u) {
    }
    public void resultadoListar(List<Usuario> lista) {
    }
    public void resultadoExcluir(boolean b) {
    }
    public void falha(String f) {
    }
}
```